# Rails escapes string inside label tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, html-safe

I have a label tag, whose content is loaded from a en.yml file.

**html.erb**

```
<%=label_tag(:name, t(:name, scope:[:helpers, :form], name: person_name(person))).html_safe%>
```

person_name is a helper and outputs a string

**persons_helper.rb**

```
def person_name(person)
    content_tag(:span,
                formatted_name(person.name) || t("helpers.persons.default_name"),
                class: 'name').html_safe
end
```

output string from the helper is passed on t method and concatenated as following

**en.yml**

```
  name: "Person Name: (%{name})"
```

I want the output to be like

```
<label for="person">
  Person Name:
  <span class='name> John Doe </span>
</label>
```

but Instead I get

```
<label for="person">
  Person Name:(&lt;span class="name"&gt;John Doe&lt;/span&gt;)
</label>
```

I understand that it got to do with html_safe, raw and escaping strings but I just could not get it to work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call `.html_safe` on the method call inside the label_tag. E.g:

```
<%=label_tag(:name, t(:name, scope:[:helpers, :form], name: person_name(person).html_safe))%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `I18n.t` method does not return a SafeBuffer (i.e. an html_safe string). So you should call `.html_safe` on the output from this method.

```
<%= label_tag(:name, t(:name, scope:[:helpers, :form], name: person_name(person)).html_safe) %>
```

Note the `.html_safe` call has been moved in one parenthesis from where you had it. This can also be made marginally easier to see by using the block form of the `label_tag` helper.

```
<%= label_tag(:name) { t("helpers.form.name", name: person_name(person)).html_safe } %>
```

Note: I also switched to the `"helpers.form.name"` method of selecting the I18n translation in this example to further increase readability (but this may be just a personal preference -- so use your original style if you prefer!).

Finally, for security purposes -- so that a user's name doesn't come through unescaped -- you should remove the `.html_safe` from your `person_name` helper and add a strict `html_escape` (or `sanitize`) so that it looks like this:

```
def person_name(person)
  content_tag(:span,
    h(formatted_name(person.name)) || t("helpers.persons.default_name"),
    class: 'name')
end
```

In this form, the `content_tag` will make sure everything is `html_safe` except for the content. Meaning that the `person.name` will come through as is and be escaped as needed. However, this is not needed if the `formatted_name` method returns an already escaped or `html_safe` name. Basically the point is that you don't want to blindly mark strings as `html_safe` when they come from user inputted values because you don't know if they contain script tags or what. Hopefully this didn't confuse. :) In general, only mark strings as `html_safe` when you are 100% sure that they are actually always going to be safe (i.e. they come from within your system and not from user input of any sort).

Answer (score 0):

Rails translations can be automatically marked as `html_safe` but using a naming convention. If a translation is suffixed with `_html` then the string is marked as `html_safe`, likewise keys named `html` are also marked as `html_safe`.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  welcome: <b>welcome!</b>
  hello_html: <b>hello!</b>
  title:
    html: <b>title!</b>
```

In the above `t('hello_html')` and `t('title.html')` will be `html_safe` strings and will not require a call to `raw` or `.html_safe` where as `t('welcome')` will not be `html_safe` and will require calling `raw` or `.html_safe` to avoid the html in the string being escaped.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations